# Use of android:anyDensity

Tags: android

I need to clear about android:anyDensity attribute with true | false,i gone through the developer guide,but i can't clear about.what the difference of using true or false value for it,Please clear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android 1.6+ `android:anyDensity` indicates whether your app supports all screen dencities. So if it is set to `true` all 1.6+ devices will be supported.

Android 1.5 doesn't support screen densities so if you have `android:anyDensity` set to `true` those devices will not be supported.